# How to copy a part of string between two symbols into another string in javascript? Help me...

Tags: javascript

```
var var1="hi (help) me";
```

I want to copy the letters between `()` into a new variable `var2`. That is, the word 'help'. Am new in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to extract the text between `parenthesis`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff45Y/)**

```
var var2 = var1.substring(var1.indexOf('(')+1, var1.indexOf(')'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice() method can be used to extract or copy a part of a string into a new string leaving the original string as it is. Here is how you can use it:

**Code:**

```js
var var1="hi (help) me"; 
var var2 = var1.slice(4,8);
console.log(var2);
```